# Stairways Hand Rail requirements

Tags: stairs, handrail

On what Building & Safety or any building' s Jurisdiction, within the United States, will this hand rail be acceptable and approved for residential usage.
[image]

Comment: Maybe  Alaska . Some of those cabins are funky.

Comment: you have to ask yourself `will this handrail prevent my fall if i trip while descending the stairs`

Comment: the second anchor from bottom looks unacceptable

Comment: The rope looks like it can slide through those hooks making it no good for a secure handrail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ICC R311.7.8 of the 2017 (current) Code requires the handrail to be no less than 1 1/4” diameter and no greater than 2” diameter. It is to be installed no less than 30” above the nosing of the stair and no greater than 38”. It shall be on one side minimum and have a minimum of 1 1/2” between it and the wall.

Handrails can be interrupted at newel posts at corners and ending points of stairs , otherwise they are to be continuous. (That is to say, you should not have to remove your hand at supports.)

Comment: You two differ 30" or 34" - a pain to be wrong...

Comment: I should have specified Ca. Building Code; it's very possible neither is wrong. Depends on authority having jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

Residential stair handrails that are circular (like rope) need to be minimum 1 1/4" diameter; is that 1 1/4" rope?

Residential stair handrails are supposed to be not less than 34" from the tread, and not more than 38". So if that rope has enough slack to be raised or lowered beyond those limitations... no good.

Comment: You two differ 30" or 34" - a pain to be wrong...

Comment: @Solar Mike, I should have specified Ca. Building Code; it's very possible neither is wrong. Depends on authority having jurisdiction.

Comment: I've met some building inspectors - some of them want to specify the color... But OP needs to make sure...